# trying to use ngSwitch in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm testing the following code in angular and it's not working. I'm very new to Angular and I've been unable to figure this out. All I'm trying to do is show a particular element based on a step number when next/back buttons are clicked.

```
  <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-switch on="selection" >
        <div ng-switch-when="2" step-number="2">Settings Div</div>
        <span ng-switch-when="1" step-number="1">Home Span</span>
        <span ng-switch-default step-number="3">default</span>
        <button ng-click="back(step-number)">back</button>
        <button ng-click="forward(step-number)">forward</button>
    </div>   
 </div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['1', '2', '3'];
    $scope.forward = function($selected) { $scope.selection = $scope.items[$selected - 1]; };
    $scope.back = function($selected) { $scope.selection = $scope.items[$selected - 1]; };
}
```

Comment: Add `console.log('$selected=',$selected);` to your `forward` or `back` methods.  That should give you a clue (while I work on writing up an answer).

Comment: i'm using alert, and it's always 0.  I wonder if it's at all binding step-number to $selected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would refactor what you are doing to the following:

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/b7mQ5ssSqECDUhvN0S2b?p=preview   (click back first).

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.selection = 2;
    $scope.items = ['div 1', 'div 2', 'div 3'];
    $scope.forward = function() { 
      if ($scope.selection==$scope.items.length-1) $scope.selection=0;
      else $scope.selection++;
      };
    $scope.back = function() { 
      if ($scope.selection==0) $scope.selection = $scope.items.length-1;
      else $scope.selection --; 
      };

    });

<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <div >
    <div>
        <div>{{items[selection]}}</div>
        <button ng-click="back()">back</button>
        <button ng-click="forward()">forward</button>
    </div>   
 </div>


</body>
```

Comment: thanks taht works.  However, if I did want to pass in a parameter from a selected item attribute, how would I do that?

Comment: you would do `back(selection)` however you already have that as a scope variable.  In general you would pass in a variable if you were in a loop and wanted to process that element. Anyways,  I updated it to allow for the forward/back to return to 0,length-1 positions as well.

Comment: I added a test function to the plunkr with an alert on the selection so you can see it.

Comment: I mean if in general I wanted to get some attribute from a form element and pass it as a param?

Comment: you would need to pass it as a string or use a scope variable.. What you are trying to do won't work UNLESS you build a directive.

Comment: <div step-number='{{selection}}' > is how you would bind it but you need to bind it to an object in the scope.

Comment: <div step-number='{{selection}}' > is how you would bind it but you need to bind it to an object in the scope.   I updated the model to show this.. check out the source and you'll see it updating with each change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `step-number`, but here is a way to make your buttons work between the values of 1 and 3 inclusive:

```
<div ng-switch on="selection">
    <div ng-switch-when="2">Settings Div</div> 
    <span ng-switch-when="1">Home Span</span>
    <span ng-switch-default step-number="3">default</span>
    <button ng-click="back()">back</button>
    <button ng-click="forward()">forward</button>
</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selection = 3;
    $scope.forward = function () {
        $scope.selection += 1;
        if ($scope.selection > 3) $scope.selection = 3;
        console.log($scope.selection);
    };
    $scope.back = function () {
        $scope.selection -= 1;
        if ($scope.selection < 1) $scope.selection = 1;
        console.log($scope.selection);
    };
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/BLxK4/)